# Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform when i try to import dart:html

Tags: html, css, dart, import

I am very new to dart so I was just trying to get this set up. I get this error when i try to run the main.dart file from the command line. Also I am not using flutter just dart, html and css.

Here is the full error:

```
Error: Dart library 'dart:html' is not available on this platform.

import 'dart:html';
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:html' is imported through these paths:

main.dart => dart:html
```

I thought maybe it was an issue with how i set up dart? When setting up I installed the dartSDK and added it to my environment variables then used sublime text as an editor. How do I get the html library?

Comment: The `dart:html` package are only available when compiling your application to JavaScript and then run your application in a browser. It cannot be used when running your dart file though the normal `dart` command. If you are starting with Dart for web development, maybe this guide would be helpful to get you started: https://dart.dev/tutorials/web/get-started

Comment: Alternative, you should remove the `dart:html` import in your Dart program if you want to run it just with the `dart` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try [universal_html](https://pub.dev/packages/universal_html) pub.

From pub's description: A cross-platform `dart:html`.